What flag had a black cross blue field 1589?
What flag is blue background and black cross flags 1589?
Used by Giovanni Batista Boazio 

What's the source of the image? Is this the best resolution that's available?

@MCW When I click on your link, it seems to open the 2nd result on my end which is this which looks different. Looks like Google's habit to tailor results depending on geographic location struck again.

We can get a better view of the image from the Library of Congress page Map and views illustrating Sir Francis Drake's West Indian voyage, 1585-6, . It appears the flag in question, by its location in North America, would be a representation of a French flag.
 The illustrator has simplified the image due to space restrictions, only showing one fleur, where there should be three. If we zoom in a little more we can see the disctinctive shape of the fleur-de-lis:

Images from LOC
Here is an Example of the full French flag from that era:


Update: A comment from @Jean Marie Becker points out that, due to the time frame this location is likely referencing the first French Colony attempt of Charlesbourg-Royal, -'established by Jacques Cartier in 1541'.


(On a side note, it seems that recent changes in my browser (Chrome) now allow full page/site language conversion with a right-click menu option. This is an extremely useful feature as foreign language wiki entries on various subjects often have much more relevant information than the English wiki versions.)

Some more infomation : the settlement with this fleur-de-lys flag must be "Charlebourg Royal" created in 1541 by explorer Jacques Cartier (see French Wikipedia article about him.
